# Linguex: \makehandout doesn't work

Tags: linguex

Putting \makehandout is supposed to extract the example sentences in Linguex, as described in the documentation (page 5). It is not working for me. Here is an minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12]{report}
\usepackage{linguex} 
\usepackage{linguho}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\title{My title}


\ex.\label{407}This is my test example

\makehandout
\end{document}
```

Comment: What error do you get? I get a `No \title given` error, which disappears if I give a `\title{...}`.

Comment: I get this warning "You have requested package `linguho', but the package provides `lingo'." The compiler couldn't finish compiling in my case.  I am using Xelatex. Could that make a difference?

Comment: A warning shouldn't make the compiler hang. Try to put `\title{something}` to see what happens.

Comment: You are right. For this test example, the problem is just the title. But, my problem is turn out to be more complicated. I think it is conflicting with other packages. I am getting errors like "Undefined control sequence. \setlength {\pgf@nodesepstart }{0pt}"; and "Package caption Error: \caption outside float. \setlength {\caption@indent }{0pt}". All these issue never happen when I disable Linguho package. I think I am giving up with it.

Comment: If your problem doesn't appear in the example code you gave us it'll be hard to solve. If you are still getting these errors, post a minimal working example that contains the commands you mentioned and that give this error.

Comment: After some tests, I realized that the problem is a conflict with XYLING & Tikz packages.  I have edited the working example to reflect the new observation.

Comment: Problem disappears if I don't use babel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a clash between `linguho` and `tikz`.

The `linguho` package writes a few commands to a .han file, which is then `\input`. The issue is that it writes

```
\setlength {\pgf@nodesepstart }{0pt}
\setlength {\pgf@nodesepend }{0pt}
```

to the .han file but does not write `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to make TeX understand the macro names.

There are two possible solutions:

The first one, and less invasive, load `tikz` *before* `linguho`.

The second, independent of package order, is to patch `linguho`'s commands to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\makehandout
  {\input\jobname.han}
  {\makeatletter\input\jobname.han}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\resetExdefaults
  {\noexpand\resetExdefaults}
  {\noexpand\resetExdefaults\noexpand\makeatother}
  {}{}
```